# No error on value outside TypeScript enum

Tags: enums, typescript

Was hoping this might produce a compile time error but I guess I have just misunderstood how enums work...

```
enum SortDirection {
    ascending = 1,
    descending = -1
}
type IndexSpec = {[index: string]: SortDirection};

var i: IndexSpec = {thing: 3};  // no compile time error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All numeric values are considered value enum values.

This is allowed because there's no distinction between flag and non-flag enums:

```
enum MyFlags {
  Cool = 0x1,
  Awesome = 0x2,
  Neat = 0x4
}

var i: MyFlags = 5; // Cool | Neat
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Ryan.  I guess the answer of "because there's no distinction between flag and non-flag enums" is implied somewhere in the source code, or perhaps it's in the [language spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#9) but I just missed it.  Thanks anyway.  You know of any way to achieve what I was trying to achieve in the question?  No worries if not :)  Thanks again!

Comment: I can't think of a way to, at compile-time, ensure that a number is in the enum. It's best to just never use numeric literals when using enums if that's a danger.